# CASE expression with LEFT function

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

**EDIT** **View looks like this**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw] AS
SELECT 
    d.Column1
    ,d.Column2
    ,d.DocumentNo
    ,d.Title AS 'abc'
    ,d.column3 AS 'def'
    ,d.column4
    ,d.column5 AS 'adad'
    ,d.CODE
    ,d.ARCHIVED
    ,d.Revised
    ,d.Received
    ,d.APPROVED
    ,d.Act
    ,d.Cat
    ,d.Column8
    ,d.Column9
    ,d.[req]
    , CASE WHEN p.ProjNo = '12345' and d.DocumentNo = LEFT(d.DocumentNo,8)) = 12345678 THEN p.ProjNo = 12345678 and p.ProjTitle = 'title1' 
      ELSE CASE WHEN p.ProjNo = '12345' and (d.DocumentNo = LEFT(d.DocumentNo,8)) = 23456789 THEN p.ProjNo = 23456789 and p.ProjTitle = 'Title2' 
      ELSE CASE WHEN p.projNo = '12345' and (d.DocumentNo = LEFT(d.DocumentNo,8)) = 34567890 THEN p.projNo = `34567890` and p.projTitile = 'Title3' 
      ELSE p.ProjNo END AS [BTProjNo] 
    ,p.ID

FROM [DB].[dbo].[Document] d
    INNER JOIN [DB].[dbo].[Project] p ON d.ProjNo = p.ProjNo
```

I'm trying to make changes to an already written one due to new company standards. In the database there is a projNo column, DocumentNo column. Now the company has split one project into 3 small projects whose ProjNo is the first 8 characters of the DocumentNo.

Tried: I tried to use a CASE expression and a LEFT function to split the DocumentNo and make it the new projNo. But I keep getting errors. I have tried with/without paranthesis it's the same

Code:

```
CASE WHEN p.ProjNo = '12345' and d.DocumentNo = LEFT(d.DocumentNo,8)) = 12345678 THEN p.ProjNo = 
         12345678 and p.ProjTitle = ' ' 
  ELSE CASE WHEN p.ProjNo = '12345' and (d.DocumentNo = LEFT(d.DocumentNo,8)) = 23456789 THEN 
           p.ProjNo = 23456789 and p.ProjTitle = ' ' 
  ELSE CASE WHEN p.projNo = '12345' and (d.DocumentNo = LEFT(d.DocumentNo,8)) = 34567890 THEN 
           p.projNo = `34567890` and p.projTitile = ' ' 
  ELSE p.ProjNo END AS [BTProjNo]
```

Errors:

> 1) An expression of non-boolean type is specified where a condition is expected - shows at the value for d.DocumentNo
>    2) Incorrect syntax near all 3 ELSE. Expecting AND,OR,THEN
>    3) Incorrect syntax near all 3 '=' Expecting AND,OR,THEN

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and help me get in the right direction?

Comment: What are you trying to do when you have a CASE WHEN A = B = C?   That is invalid syntax, and I don't understand what you think it's supposed to do.

Comment: Your code is full of syntactical errors. Post sample data and expected results and explain what you want to do.

Comment: @avery I am trying to change a view.. Currently it has p.projNo, d.DocumentNo and all the joins in place. I am trying to use the CASE statement for p.ProjNo column to include 3 new p.projNo. The 3 new p.projNo are the first 8 characters in d.DocumentNo .. Hope this is clear? I am new and sucking at it right now..

Comment: You need to post the existing View, or at least enough of it so we can see what you are trying to modify.

Comment: I still think my answer does what you are describing.  It either needs to replace p.ProjNo in the select, or it may need to be added into a subquery or even a join clause.

Comment: @avery_larry  I added the view

Comment: Are you saying that is the currently functioning view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still trying to understand what, if anything, is currently working so we can understand how to fix what isn't working.  But I'll try something else:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw] AS
SELECT 
    d.Column1
    ,d.Column2
    ,d.DocumentNo
    ,d.Title AS 'abc'
    ,d.column3 AS 'def'
    ,d.column4
    ,d.column5 AS 'adad'
    ,d.CODE
    ,d.ARCHIVED
    ,d.Revised
    ,d.Received
    ,d.APPROVED
    ,d.Act
    ,d.Cat
    ,d.Column8
    ,d.Column9
    ,d.[req]
    , CASE WHEN p.ProjNo = '12345' and LEFT(d.DocumentNo,8)) = 12345678 THEN 12345678
           WHEN p.ProjNo = '12345' and LEFT(d.DocumentNo,8)) = 23456789 THEN 23456789
           WHEN p.projNo = '12345' and LEFT(d.DocumentNo,8)) = 34567890 THEN 34567890
           ELSE p.ProjNo END AS [BTProjNo]
    , CASE WHEN p.ProjNo = '12345' and LEFT(d.DocumentNo,8)) = 12345678 THEN 'title1'
           WHEN p.ProjNo = '12345' and LEFT(d.DocumentNo,8)) = 23456789 THEN 'title2'
           WHEN p.projNo = '12345' and LEFT(d.DocumentNo,8)) = 34567890 THEN 'title3'
           ELSE p.ProjTitle END AS ProjTitle
    ,p.ID

FROM [DB].[dbo].[Document] d
    INNER JOIN [DB].[dbo].[Project] p ON d.ProjNo = p.ProjNo
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are using CASE in your update statement, right?

```
       SELECT
            CASE WHEN p.ProjNo = '12345' and LEFT(d.DocumentNo,8) IN(12345678,23456789, 34567890) THEN LEFT(d.DocumentNo,8) ELSE p.ProjNo END AS ProjNo ,
           CASE WHEN p.ProjNo = '12345' and LEFT(d.DocumentNo,8) IN(12345678,23456789, 34567890) THEN N'' ELSE p.projTitile END AS projTitile
    FROM yourtable p
INNER JOIN document d
ON ...
```

Comment: I am trying to change the code in the view. So before there was a p.projNo column. I am trying to use the CASE statement within that column..

Comment: If it is in a view, it is a SELECT statement. Updated

Comment: I still get the error -  "An expression of non-boolean type is specified where a condition is expected" - at LEFT(d.DocumentNo,8))

Comment: I had extra brackets. removed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
CASE WHEN p.ProjNo = '12345' THEN LEFT(d.DocumentNo,8)) else p.ProjNo end AS ProjNo
```

This is how you would use ProjNo unless the ProjNo is '12345' then in that case you would substitute the first 8 of the DocumentNo.  You would use this in your select statements and/or join statements.

If ProjTitle is also affected, then a *separate* case statement for it:

```
CASE WHEN p.ProjNo = '12345' THEN ' ' ELSE p.ProjTitle end AS ProjTitle
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the '12345' is being split in 3 baby projects each with a different projNo and projTitle

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here - it still all seems a bit unclear - this 8 digit document number is also the project number as well (ie also 8 digits too), so maybe what you need is to change that join condition ...

```
INNER JOIN [DB].[dbo].[Project] p 
ON ( 
       (d.ProjNo = p.ProjNo) 
       OR 
       (len(d.DocumentNumber) = 8 AND d.DocumentNo = p.ProjNo)
   )
```